# Post related information in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to show post related information in Wordpress, like date when it is posted,no. of comments, Tags & read more button. Is there plugin for that or settings to do that

Comment: You'll have to modify your loop. Comfortable with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several post related Template Tags are available in Wordpress. Check out Wordpress's office document [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags). You need to call those inside the Wordpress [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).  Example, `the_tags()`, `the_date()`, `next_post_link()`, `previous_post_link()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Will depend on your theme's implementation of the loop. Basically you should be modifying your `single.php` (viewable from Appearance->Editor) file and adding/formatting required information. Check out [the loop on Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [The Loop in action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) for real live examples.